# JOOQ multiple select count in one connection with PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I have a table `SUBSCRIPTION`, I want to run multiple `selectCount` written with JOOQ in one connection with different predicates to the database.
To do so, I have created a list of queries:

```
List<Query> countQueries = channels.stream().map(c ->
                selectCount().from(SUBSCRIPTION)
                        .innerJoin(SENDER).on(SENDER.ID.equal(SUBSCRIPTION.SENDER_ID))
                        .innerJoin(CHANNEL).on(CHANNEL.ID.equal(SUBSCRIPTION.CHANNEL_ID))
                        .where(SENDER.CODE.equal(senderCode))
                        .and(CHANNEL.CODE.equal(c))
        ).collect(toList());
```

And finally, I have launched this list of queries using `batch`:

```
using(configuration).batch(countQueries).execute();
```

I have expected to have the results of the above queries in the return values of `execute`, but I get an array of integer filled with `0` values.

Is this the right way to run multiple `selectCount` using JOOQ?
What is the signification of the integer array returned by the `execute` method?

I have checked this [link](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/04/20/how-to-calculate-multiple-aggregate-functions-in-a-single-query/), in the JOOQ blog, talking about "How to Calculate Multiple Aggregate Functions in a Single Query", but It's just about SQL queries, no JOOQ dialects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Comments on your assumptions

> I have expected to have the results of the above queries in the return values of execute, but I get an array of integer filled with 0 values.

The `batch()` API can only be used for DML queries (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`), just like with native JDBC. I mean, you can run the queries as a batch, but you cannot fetch the results this way.

> I have checked this [link](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/04/20/how-to-calculate-multiple-aggregate-functions-in-a-single-query/), in the JOOQ blog, talking about "How to Calculate Multiple Aggregate Functions in a Single Query", but It's just about SQL queries, no JOOQ dialects.

Plain SQL queries almost always translate quite literally to jOOQ, so you can apply the technique from that article also in your case. In fact, you should! Running so many queries is definitely not a good idea.

#### Translating that linked query to jOOQ

So, let's look at how to translate that plain SQL example from the link to your case:

```java
Record record =
ctx.select(
      channels.stream()
              .map(c -> count().filterWhere(CHANNEL.CODE.equal(c)).as(c))
              .collect(toList())
   )
   .from(SUBSCRIPTION)
   .innerJoin(SENDER).on(SENDER.ID.equal(SUBSCRIPTION.SENDER_ID))
   .innerJoin(CHANNEL).on(CHANNEL.ID.equal(SUBSCRIPTION.CHANNEL_ID))
   .where(SENDER.CODE.equal(senderCode))
   .and(CHANNEL.CODE.in(channels)) // Not strictly necessary, but might speed up things
   .fetch();
```

This will produce a single record containing all the count values.

As always, this is assuming the following static import

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

#### Using classic `GROUP BY`

Of course, you can also just use a classic `GROUP BY` in your particular case. This might even be a bit faster:

```java
Result<?> result =
ctx.select(CHANNEL.CODE, count())
   .from(SUBSCRIPTION)
   .innerJoin(SENDER).on(SENDER.ID.equal(SUBSCRIPTION.SENDER_ID))
   .innerJoin(CHANNEL).on(CHANNEL.ID.equal(SUBSCRIPTION.CHANNEL_ID))
   .where(SENDER.CODE.equal(senderCode))
   .and(CHANNEL.CODE.in(channels)) // This time, you need to filter
   .groupBy(CHANNEL.CODE)
   .fetchOne();
```

This now produces a table with one count value per code. Alternatively, fetch this into a `Map<String, Integer>`:

```java
Map<String, Integer> map =
ctx.select(CHANNEL.CODE, count())
   .from(SUBSCRIPTION)
   .innerJoin(SENDER).on(SENDER.ID.equal(SUBSCRIPTION.SENDER_ID))
   .innerJoin(CHANNEL).on(CHANNEL.ID.equal(SUBSCRIPTION.CHANNEL_ID))
   .where(SENDER.CODE.equal(senderCode))
   .and(CHANNEL.CODE.in(channels))
   .groupBy(CHANNEL.CODE)
   .fetchMap(CHANNEL.CODE, count());
```